# {"The input string was not in a correct format."}

Tags: c#, oracle

I have this code where I'm doing a insert and the return is giving me this error. 
Here is my Functions:

> **{"The input string was not in a correct format."}**

```
public DataTable table(List<cliente> cli)
        {
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            data.Columns.Add("STATUS");
            data.Columns.Add("FILIAL");
            // here i add 54 columns

            for (int i = 0; i < cli.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = data.NewRow();
                row["STATUS"] = status;
                row["FILIAL"] = filial;
                // here i add 54 rows
            }
            insert(data);

            return data;
        }




 public void insert(DataTable dt)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var conn = new conexao_banco().conecta_banco())
                {
                    #region lista de arrays para cada item
                    // here i add 54 arrays including date and double
                    int[] status = new int[dt.Rows.Count];
                    string[] filial = new string[dt.Rows.Count];

                    #endregion lista de arrays para cada item

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        status[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]?["STATUS"]);
                        filial[i] = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]?["FILIAL"]);
                        // here i convert the arrays including date and double
                    }

                    #region oracleparameter
                    // I do the same here for all 54 columns
                    OracleParameter cliente_status = new OracleParameter();
                    cliente_status.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
                    cliente_status.Value = status[0];

                    OracleParameter cliente_filial = new OracleParameter();
                    cliente_filial.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                    cliente_filial.Value = filial[0];

                    #endregion oracleparameter

                    conn.CommandText = "Insert into ped_ven_base" +
                        " (STATUS,FILIAL,TIPO_PEDIDO,KEY_PEDIDO_BASE,NUM_PEDIDO_INTERNO,NUM_PEDIDO_CLIENTE," +
                        "NUM_PEDIDO_VENDEDOR,COD_CLIENTE,FILIAL_CLIENTE,TEXTO_PADRAO_1,TEXTO_PADRAO_2,COD_TRANSACAO_1," +
                        "COD_TRANSACAO_2,COD_TRANSACAO_3,USUARIO_EMITENTE,USUARIO_CANCELADOR,MOTIVO_CANCELAMENTO," +
                        "DATA_EMISSAO,DATA_DIGITACAO,RAZAO_SOCIAL,ENDERECO,CEP,CGC_CIC,OBSERVACOES,COND_PAGTO,DATA_VALIDADE," +
                        "SITUACAO_PEDIDO,NOME_COMPRADOR,EMAIL,FONE,FAX,ENDERECO_COBRANCA,CEP_COBRANCA,USER_STRING,DATA_FECHADO," +
                        "DESTINO_USO,COD_FLAG_PEDIDO,DATA_PREVISTA_FATURAMENTO,STATUS_DE_LIBERACAO,USUARIO_LIBERACAO,DATA_LIBERACAO," +
                        "NOTAF_ORC,OBSERVACOES_REP,GERADO_AUTOMATICO,QTD_IMP_ETIQ,RAZAO_LOJISTA,VLR_TOT_IPI,KEY_NOTAF_BASE,PEDIDO_PAGO," +
                        "AGENCIA,FILIAL_AGENCIA,TIPO_COMISSAO,VALOR_COMISSAO,KEY_ORDEM_BASE)" +
                        " values (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16,:17,:18," +
                        ":19,:20,:21,:22,:23,:24,:25,:26,:27,:28,:29,:30,:31,:32,:33,:34," +
                        ":35,:36,:37,:38,:39,:40,:41,:42,:43,:44,:45,:46,:47,:48,:49,:50,:51,:52,:53,:54)";

                    #region adiciona paramentros no insert

                    // here I Add all the parameters from the OracleParameter I created.
                    conn.Parameters.Add(cliente_status);
                    conn.Parameters.Add(cliente_filial);

                    #endregion adiciona paramentros no insert

                    conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I removed part of the code to make easier to read. If you guys want I can publish the role code. Mostly of what I removed, I added a comment on the code.

Here is the full exception:

```
System.FormatException: A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.
   em System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   em System.Number.ParseInt64(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   em System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
   em System.Convert.ToInt64(Object value)
   em OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleParameterImpl.SetInt32DataInBytes(Object paramValue, Byte[]& int32ByteArray)
   em OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleParameterImpl.SetInt32DataInBytes(Object paramValue)
   em Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind_Int32()
   em Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind(OracleConnectionImpl connImpl, ColumnDescribeInfo cachedParamMetadata, Boolean& bMetadataModified, Int32 arrayBindCount, ColumnDescribeInfo& paramMetaData, Object& paramValue, Boolean isEFSelectStatement, SqlStatementType stmtType)
   em OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.InitializeParamInfo(ICollection paramColl, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, ColumnDescribeInfo[] cachedParamMetadata, Boolean& bMetadataModified, Boolean isEFSelectStatement, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper& marshalBindValuesHelper)
   em OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ProcessParameters(OracleParameterCollection paramColl, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, ColumnDescribeInfo[] cachedParamMetadata, Boolean& bBindMetadataModified, Boolean isEFSelectStatement, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper& marshalBindValuesHelper)
   em OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, Boolean isFromEF)
   em Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   em promobimp.banco.insere_pedido.insere_base(DataTable dt) na C:\Users\Mario\Documents\projetos\marimport\banco\insere_pedido.cs:linha 625
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Most of this code isn't related to the error. What would help, the full exception text including the call stack, is missing. Where is the exception thrown? The error means that the code is trying to convert a string to a date or number using the wrong locale.

Comment: Probably you have something wrong going on with all those parameters. Try printing out the query before `conn.ExecuteNonQuery()` and run it yourself on the database to see what happens...

Comment: @JoãoMenighin that's a .NET error.

Comment: You should take the habit of properly declaring your columns. Instead of `data.Columns.Add("STATUS");` you should always create column with explicit types. Instead use `data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("STATUS", typeof(string)));`

Comment: Does the error occur in  `status[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]?["STATUS"]);` ? What is stored in there? What does `status` contain?

Comment: I added the full exception error. Is  throwing the exception on `conn.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: I agree with @PanagiotisKanavos.  It seems as if one of the values from `filial[]` is not an integer.  Maybe it has alpha characters, maybe it's null?  Try to print them all out before you insert and see which one is causing the problem converting from string to int.